# Database Web Frontend

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, frontend

I'm looking for a **web frontend for end users** of our database (server runs either MySQL or PostgreSQL) for organization-internal contacts and order handling.

I've searched the web for free/opensource database web frontends but only found admin tools (phpMyAdmin, ...) and frameworks that only show the tables but you cannot create apps (dadabik, vfront, xataface).

I want to **create apps like in Access forms** but apparently there is no such tool out there... As a backup, I would use openoffice Base with JDBC connection or progam the frontend in PHP manually.

An advantage would be **user authentication** (preferably LDAP).

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question would probably be better served on http://serverfault.com/ . (pun intended).

Comment: Hi, I'm just curious to understand better which are the Access features you miss in DaDaBIK.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [OpenXava](http://www.openxava.org) this might be what you are looking for.